# Convert timestamp with time zone to date. Possible with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, spring, date, converters

My Spring web app is storing timestamps with time zone in Postgre database. Right now, I'm using `Thymeleaf` and displaying raw timestamps on frontend. Those timestamps look really bad, so I want to convert them to local date and time.

I know there's an option to convert them right after they're retrieved via repository from the database, but I've been told that there's better way using JavaScript. I've searched for a bit, but found no solution so far.

I just need a keyword I can read on. Any leads on how to use JS to convert that?

Comment: Have you looked into using moment.js?

Comment: The best way to store date/time will be in ISO format. In javascript you can create date/time in ISO format using `toISOString()`

Comment: What do your timestamps look like now? Also, do you want the time to be localized to the client time zone (JavaScript) or the time zone on your server?

Comment: Timestamps look pretty much like that: `2018-04-18T20:31:17.643+02:00`. I want it to be localized to the client time zone.

Comment: If I already have a view with such value rendered, is it even possible to access that value, format it and then reload the view with JS? Or is accessing the DB the only option?

Comment: Writing a parser for a single format isn't difficult, maybe 10 lines of code if you need timezone offset also. There are also a number of good parsing and formatting libraries. Chose one.

Comment: Put extra information in the question, don't hide it in comments.